# Mouse event e (Jpanel) Java help

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I want a MouseListener for a JPanel inside a JTabbedPane in a JFrame...
I want it to print something, whenever the mouse is clicked/pressed.
I've tried looking around but when I try and implement it I got an error on this line:

```
public class GUI implements ActionListener, MouseListener
```

And this is the error:

> `GUI` is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method `mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)` in `java.awt.event.MouseListener`

What does that mean?

P.S (the JPanel/tab bit I want it in is called: displayMainPanel)
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
jPanel.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("mouseClicked");
                }
                public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("mouseEntered");
                }
                public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("mouseExited");
                }
                public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("mousePressed");
                }
                public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("mouseReleased");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to override `mouseExit`:

In your `GUI` class:

```
@Override
public void mouseExit(MouseEvent e) { /* Do nothing */ }
```

When all errors are gone. Don't forget to `yourPanel.addMouseListener(theMouseListener)`:

```
yourPanel.addMouseListener(theObjectOfTheClassWhichImplementsTheListener);
```

And then set the focus an the panel, to be sure events will be caught.

```
yourPanel.requestFocus();
```